# org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId

Tags: java, xml, tomcat, saxparseexception

I tried to deploy a .war file to tomcat but encounter the following problem:

> INFO: Deploying web application archive [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\workflow.war]
> Nov 13, 2020 11:11:55 AM org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSourceFactory getObjectInstance
> INFO: Name = workflow Ignoring unknown property: value of "Workflow" for "description" property
> Nov 13, 2020 11:11:55 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester fatalError
> SEVERE: Parse fatal error at line [1] column [1]
> org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/C:/Program%20Files/Apache%20Software%20Foundation/Tomcat%209.0/webapps/workflow/WEB-INF/tags/; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog.
> at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:204)
> at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:178)
> at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:400)
> at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:327)
> at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.reportFatalError(XMLScanner.java:1471)
> at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:978)
> at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:605)
> at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:112)
> at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:541)
> at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:888)
> at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:824)
> at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
> at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1224)
> at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:635)
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1551)
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.tld.TldParser.parse(TldParser.java:76)
> at org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJspConfig(TldScanner.java:198)
> at org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scan(TldScanner.java:102)
> at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperInitializer.onStartup(JasperInitializer.java:83)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5166)
> at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:717)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:690)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:706)
> at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:978)
> at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1848)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:118)
> at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:773)
> at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:427)
> at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1576)
> at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:309)
> at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
> at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:423)
> at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:366)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:936)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:843)
> at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
> at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:421)
> at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:930)
> at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
> at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:772)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
> at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:342)
> at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:473)

It is strange that it doesn't not reported which xml file has problem, and I also find all xml files inside my project without any problem, there is no .xsd files in my project.
Is anyone can help to find out where problem is?

Thanks

Comment: more findings:
Where i comment out the <taglib> in web.xml, the application ca be started. However, some of my pages cannot be loaded due to no <taglib-uri>

Comment: there is NO xml files inside my <taglib-uri> location.....

Comment: Weird. It looks like the XML parser is trying to load a directory for parsing. I didn't think that would *ever* work on Windows, though it's possible to "open" a directory on a *NIX filesystem as if it were a normal file. Can you think of anywhere a file should be specified, but it's either blank or might point to a directory instead of a real file?